# Angular 2 with eventemiiter doesnot work

Tags: angular

i am using angular 2 with develop Ecommerce app.

I tried to Event Emitter because I add any product into cart and display the count value in cart icon.

Here is my Home component.

```
import { Component, OnInit,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  badge;
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

     addtocart(deal, value) {
      this.badge=1;
      this.change.emit(this.badge);
     }
}
```

When I click the `addtocart` button.I emit the `badge` value.

Here is my menubar component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
export class MenubarComponent implements OnInit {
 badge:any;
 change1(user)
    {
      this.badge=user;
      console.log("called",this.badge);
    }

}
```

Here is my `menubar.html`

```
<span (change)="change1($event)">{{badge}}</span>
```

Here is home component.html.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" *ngFor="let deals of deals; let i = index;">
                        <div class=" deals-blk" *ngIf="i < 4">                                
                            <a href="deals-details.html"><img src="http://35.154.116.133/crackerdeals/deals/{{deals.D_IMAGES[0].URL}}" alt="DEALs"></a>

                            <div class="deals-blk-details clearfix">              
                                <h3>{{deals.D_NAME}}</h3>
                                <p class="short-desc">For duration of 2hours and budget of 3K</p>
                                <p class="net-val">Net Value: {{settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_SYMBOL}} {{deals.D_SALE_PRICE}}</p>
                                <p class="prod-val">{{settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_SYMBOL}} {{deals.D_REGULAR_PRICE}} + {{deals.D_TAX[0].PERCENTAGE}}% GST</p>
                                <div class="row clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 selectbox">    
                                        <select  name="" id="" #sval>
                                            <option *ngFor="let select of selectval" value="{{select.value}}" [selected]="select.value === '1'">{{select.value}}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-9">                       
                                        <button class="col-sm-8" (click)="addtocart(deals,sval.value)">ADD TO CART</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Actually i am using ngfor display list of product.

```
sval.value is count value.`deals` is a product.
```

But not display the `badge` value how can i do this?

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: is your console log printing the value??

Comment: do they have a parent child relationship @vaishuani

Comment: At minimum try doing 'this.change.emit(this.badge);' with this.badge rather than just badge into the emit.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.No does not consoled the value.

Comment: `this.change.emit(badge);` should be `this.change.emit(this.badge);`

Comment: @RahulSingh.I also tried to this.badge.But dont work

Comment: does not call the change1($event).

Comment: Can you show `HomeComponent.html`?

Comment: @echonax.Kindly check it.I update my code.

Comment: use another name for the emitter event ( don't use change)

Comment: That can't be the full html. Where do you use the child selector?

Comment: try name other than `change` may be ?

Comment: post full HTML of your parent component; show us parent child relationship of your component

Comment: are you emitting event from Parent to child  @vaishuani?

Comment: Ya.I updated.@Rahul

Comment: Where is the child component in the html?

Comment: @Rahul.This is my path src\app\pages\home\home.component and src\app\shared\menubar\menubar.component.ts

Comment: @vaishuani we cant see menubar component inside your homecomponent

Comment: @vaishuani i guess your component doesn't have parent child relationship

Comment: @Rahul.k How can i do it. any other way.Thanks for ur patient.Kindly pls advice me.

Comment: @vaishuani where are you using menubar component ?

Comment: menubar component using display header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152215/discussion-between-rahul-and-vaishu-ani).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  badge : number = null;
  @Output() badgetChanged = new EventEmitter();
     addtocart(deal, value) {
      this.badge = 1;
      this.badgetChanged.emit(this.badge);
     }
}
```

HTML :

```
<span (badgetChanged)="badgetChanged($event)">{{badge}}</span>
```

Other TS :

```
badgetChanged(event : number) : void {
  this.badge = event;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I used this still does not wrk.why?

Comment: Please try now. change the event function name and catch the event in the other ts file

Comment: This is my path.This is my path src\app\pages\home\home.component and src\app\shared\menubar\menubar.component.ts.I tried to this.But dont wrk